# Thread call window form control

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, thread-safety

I want to make thread can call window form control. I make this:

```
delegate void SetTextCallback(String str, int i);
private void SetText(string text, int i)
{
    // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the 
    // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread. 
    // If these threads are different, it returns true. 
    if (this.label2.InvokeRequired)
    {
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text,i});
    }
    else
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                this.label1.Text = text;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.label2.Text = text;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

But it seem too long because I want to call **many form obj**( label1, label2, textbox,...) -> case 1,2,3,4,5 and we will have **many case**.

Is there a better way?
With out **int i** in SetText(string text, int i)

Another way

Not using **switch(i)** to know which obj need changing text

**=====update=====**

this is the code in thread

```
SetText("This text for the first label",1);
SetText("This text for the second label",2);
```

Comment: Which part is too long, the `switch` statement or the `Invoke` part? You should consider passing in a reference to the actual label.

Comment: I don't like the int i varible to know with obj is called

Answer (score 4):

I user a couple of extension methods for this.

```
public static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void SafeInvoke(this Control control, Action action) 
    {
        if(control.InvokeRequired) 
        {
            control.BeginInvoke(action);
        }
        else 
        {
            action();
        }
    }
}
```

and then to use it, something like this.

```
public void TreeCompleted(bool completed)
{
    this.SafeInvoke(() =>
    {
        if(completed) 
        {
            DiagnosisTree = treeBranchControl1.GetDiagnosisTree(null);

            pctLoader.Visible = false;
            btnSelectDiagnosis.Visible = false;
            lblDiagnosis.Visible = true;
            treeBranchControl1.Visible = true;
        }
        else 
        {
            DiagnosisId = 0;
            DiagnosisTree = null;
        }
    });   
}
```

this is the form or control where the code is running.

In your case, you do do this:

```
public void SetText(string text, int i)
{
    this.SafeInvoke(() =>
    {
        switch (i)
        {
            case 1:
                this.label1.Text = text;
                break;
            case 2:
                this.label2.Text = text;
                break;
        }
    });   
}
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution. +1

Comment: I am not clear about this. Could you make a sample code to set text?

Comment: Oh I see. But this not what I mean. I tired of the int i varible. Is there any way with out int i.

Comment: I can't follow you. int i? @user1614028

Comment: Yes, same here. That's your code, only you know what the int represents here.

Comment: private void SetText(string text, int i). I use i to know which form obj need to be set a new text.

Comment: But how is it getting called. What is the code that calls that method?  What determines how the integer value is set and used?